Mutual information upper-bound
For a given $c\in(0,1)$, a positive integer $n$ and independent random variables $X$ and $Y$, I am interested in obtaining an upper-bound on the mutual information between $c^n X+Y$ and $X$.
One (almost trivial) upper-bound is $\text{I}(c^n X+Y; X)\leq \text{H}(X)$ (where $\text{H}(X)$ is the entropy of $X$), which can be obtained by an application of the data-processing inequality, followed by the chain-rule for mutual information.
However, I believe something  stronger can be obtained based on the following informal observation: for very large $n$, $I(c^nX+Y;X)\approx I(Y;X)=0$ (by independence).
I am looking for an upper-bound that converges to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity, any help would be appreciated!

This depends a fair bit on the structure of $X,Y$, and you should think about what kind of regime you're working in. Two illustrative examples follow. 1. If $X,Y$ are independent Gaussians, then you get $\frac{1}{2} \log(1 + \mathrm{SNR}) = \frac12 \log(1 + \kappa c^{2n}) \le \kappa c^{2n}/2,$ where $\kappa = \sigma^2_X/\sigma^2_Y.$ 2. If $X,Y$ are finite support, then in fact you should have mutual information $H(X)$  for large $n$: suppose the minimum distance between two elements in the support of $Y$ is $\Delta$, and the largest absolute value of any element in the support of $X$ is $M$.

(continued) Then for $n$ so large that $c^n M < \Delta/2,$ on observing $c^n X + Y,$ you can decode the actual $Y$ value with certainty (e.g., map to the closest $Y$-support element), which tells you $c^n X,$ and thus $X$, with certainty. Point of all this is that the structure/scenario you're working with matters, and without it it's hard to say anything very concrete.

@stochasticboy321 thank you, very nice intuitive example!
